# Python GUI quit doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

I am learning how to create a GUI with Pyqt5 and QT-Designer and I have a problem with the *Cancel* button which should just close the GUI Window.
I used this function `QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()` to quit but it does not work.

The whole code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QToolTip

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(524, 201)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 50, 151, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Algerian")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButton.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 161, 51))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 524, 31))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
         #####
        self.pushButton.setToolTip('this is just a <u> Button </u>')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.press)
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('Times New Roman',14))
        MainWindow.setToolTip('my window!')
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        ###

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Press Here"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancel!"))

    def press(self): #1
        print('Hallo World!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle('Mein QT Windwow')
    MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QIcon('MeinBild.png'))
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have tried and for me it works correctly. Another option would be to use: `self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(MainWindow.close)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code work fine with me, try to replace:

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
```

with:

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(MainWindow.close)
```

Hope that's help, don't forget to close topic if your problem solved.